# Copy CSV data to Azure SQL database with nullable columns

Tags: csv, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I have CSV files, where some of the columns are empty. I would like to insert NULL for all nullable SQL table target columns. Where do I do that mapping? The ADF editor does not give me any options that I can see.

Comment: Hello, can my answer be helpful for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could follow my steps.

This my csv file:

[image]

This my sink table schema:

```
create table test3(
    id int,
    name varchar(50),
    age int
)
```

Copy active:

**Source:**

[image]

**Sink:**

Just choose the destination table in Sink dataset
[image]

**Mapping:**

I mapping the column manually:
[image]

That's all the operations, run the pipeline:
[image]

The empty column in csv will be inserted to table as `NULL`:

[image]

Hope this help.